# Stop Outbound SYN Scan

Tags: linux, networking, debian, firewall, openvpn

Hello I run a VPN company, and recently my host has been sending me these complaints that are likely coming from a user.

I am not sure how to identify the user, if I could just do that I wouldn't need to firewall these I could just ban him.

or

How do I just stop these from happening, I tried google and everything there are absolutely zero resources for this.

Here is the email I got from my host

```
    Dear Customer,

Abnormal activity has been detected on your VPS.


Please do not hesitate to contact our technical support team so that this situation does not become critical.

You will find the logs brought up by our system below, which led to this alert.

- START OF ADDITIONAL INFORMATION -

Attack detail : 4K scans
dateTime                   srcIp:srcPort           dstIp:dstPort           protocol flags       bytes reason
2015.03.10 04:47:14 CET    1.1.1.1:51872    117.177.202.102:8123    TCP      SYN            48 SCAN:SYN
2015.03.10 04:47:14 CET    1.1.1.1:52619    223.82.243.252:8123     TCP      SYN            52 SCAN:SYN
2015.03.10 04:47:14 CET    1.1.1.1:51894    117.171.183.23:8123     TCP      SYN            48 SCAN:SYN
2015.03.10 04:47:14 CET    1.1.1.1:51969    223.87.139.126:8123     TCP      SYN            48 SCAN:SYN
2015.03.10 04:47:14 CET    1.1.1.1:52661    183.220.40.138:8123     TCP      SYN            52 SCAN:SYN
2015.03.10 04:47:14 CET    1.1.1.1:59406    168.63.20.19:8123       TCP      SYN            52 SCAN:SYN
2015.03.10 04:47:14 CET    1.1.1.1:52010    183.218.127.28:8123     TCP      SYN            48 SCAN:SYN
2015.03.10 04:47:14 CET    1.1.1.1:52026    183.218.88.130:8123     TCP      SYN            48 SCAN:SYN
2015.03.10 04:47:14 CET    1.1.1.1:52024    183.221.53.176:8123     TCP      SYN            48 SCAN:SYN
2015.03.10 04:47:14 CET    1.1.1.1:52030    117.164.27.242:8123     TCP      SYN            48 SCAN:SYN
2015.03.10 04:47:14 CET    1.1.1.1:53293    60.190.189.214:8123     TCP      SYN            52 SCAN:SYN
2015.03.10 04:47:14 CET    1.1.1.1:52052    117.173.50.98:8123      TCP      SYN            48 SCAN:SYN
2015.03.10 04:47:14 CET    1.1.1.1:52058    117.173.55.244:8123     TCP      SYN            48 SCAN:SYN
2015.03.10 04:47:14 CET    1.1.1.1:52060    183.219.218.176:8123    TCP      SYN            48 SCAN:SYN
2015.03.10 04:47:14 CET    1.1.1.1:52063    117.164.168.148:8123    TCP      SYN            48 SCAN:SYN
2015.03.10 04:47:14 CET    1.1.1.1:52103    218.204.156.111:8123    TCP      SYN            48 SCAN:SYN
2015.03.10 04:47:14 CET    1.1.1.1:52106    183.220.40.146:8123     TCP      SYN            48 SCAN:SYN
2015.03.10 04:47:14 CET    1.1.1.1:54619    117.172.168.229:8123    TCP      SYN            52 SCAN:SYN
2015.03.10 04:47:14 CET    1.1.1.1:54641    117.173.36.73:8123      TCP      SYN            52 SCAN:SYN
2015.03.10 04:47:14 CET    1.1.1.1:54488    112.45.101.145:8123     TCP      SYN            52 SCAN:SYN
```

Could I just ban all outbound on port 8123 would that solve it? If so how is that possible?

Comment: Doesn't your VPN software have logs showing what ip address was/is assigned to the user?

Comment: All of my users are on the same ip address

Comment: I just have 1 server for now

Comment: Then you need to somehow add logging on the NAT performed by your server, so that you know which ports get assigned to which VPN network hosts at all times. This log is going to be huge though.